# HttpRequestException thrown from docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm trying to set up docker image for an asp.net core api. I managed to set up it but in one of my functionalities i'm sending request to 3rd party service. And at that point of time app start throwing following exception:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> I'm building docker image by following code:

```
docker run -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" -e "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=32788" -p 32789:80 -p 32788:443 -e Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/root/.dotnet/https/selfsignedcertificate.pfx -e Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=ufo -v D:\spike\:/root/.dotnet/https myapp
```

Does anyone seen such an exception?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ?